# Remote debug over vagrant GO

Tags: go, vagrant, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, delve

I'm using vagrant with 16.04 image on host also ubuntu 16.04 
On vagrant I start

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log
```

my launch my json:

[image]

but vscode start on local he is not connected to the port in vagrant :

> config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2345, host: 2345, id:
>   "debuggolang", host_ip: "localhost", auto_correct: true

when I try to put him in convention format :

[image]

break point doesn't stop

[image]

and dlv exit

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it
I need to put the path to the root of my project in:

> remotePath